# Paypal Integration giving error

Tags: ios, paypal, crash, unrecognized-selector

Hi i am trying to integrate Paypal service but its giving error

**Error :**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-   [PayPalPaymentViewController payPalServiceManager]: unrecocnized selector sent to instance 0x12784450'
```

**Code :**

```
- (IBAction)buttonPaypalAction:(id)sender
{
gateway = @"Paypal";
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[appDelegate.orderDetails  objectAtIndex:6]];
payment.currencyCode = appDelegate.currencyCode;
payment.shortDescription = @"Food items";

if (!payment.processable) {
    // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
    // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
    // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
    // to handle that here.
}

    // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
   // self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = self.acceptCreditCards;

 PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment                                                                 configuration:self.payPalConfig                                                                              delegate:self];

// error is coming after this line...
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Are you following this? https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md

Comment: yes... it is necessary to write below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method because i do not have written in that method but in some other page                                                            [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
                                                         PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];

Comment: @Nisha please review the console log for additional messages appearing prior to the `NSInvalidArgumentException`. For example, is there a message indicating the payment was not, in fact, "processable" -- something that your code is not yet checking for. Also, please check that your `paymentViewController` is not `nil`.

Comment: @DaveGoldman thank u but i do not have added -lc++ -ObjC in other linked flags thats why error is coming now it is solved..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forgot to add -lc++ -ObjC in Other linker flags